# Inject viewModel to @Composable

Tags: android, kotlin, dependency-injection, android-jetpack-compose, koin

I have viewModel for my ProfileScreen.

```
@Composable
fun ProfileScreen() {
    val viewModel: ProfileViewModel = viewModel()
    ...
}
```

Every time when I call ProfileScreen, new viewModel is created. How can I created only one viewModel instance for my ProfileScreen. I tried to inject viewModel following https://insert-koin.io/docs/reference/koin-android/compose/ but when I try

val viewModel: ProfileViewModel = viewModel()

Android Studio throws error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or use `remember()` for save instance ViewModel between recompose calls

```
@Composable
fun ProfileScreen() {
    val viewModel = remember { ProfileViewModel() }
    ...
}
```

Also, [rememberSaveable](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state#restore-ui-state) allows saving state(aka data class) between recreating of activity

Comment: When I try it I get error comes from remeber{}: remember calls must not return Unit,

Type mismatch.
Required:
ProfileViewModel
Found:
Unit

Should I define somewhere my ProfileViewModel() class?

Comment: By calling remember it will survive recomposition, but no't if device orientation will change. It will act like a normal class which is remember in current composition, not like a typical android viewModel.

Comment: `remember` will also not survive if the ProfileScreen is in the back stack (when using Compose Navigation or Fragments) or with any other configuration change (like split-screen, dark mode switch, etc.), not just orientation change.

Comment: This is a bad pattern

Answer (score 3):

Your `viewModel` gets destroyed whenever you destroy the composable, it can survive *re-compositions* but as soon as your composable gets destroyed it will be destroyed.

What you can do is create the `viewModel` in a scope that lives longer than the ProfileScreen composable and then pass the `viewModel` as parameter to it.

Something like this should work.

```
@Composable 
fun MainScreen() {
     val vModel : ProfileViewModel = viewModel()
     ....
     ProfileScreen(vModel)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If u want to use Koin to inject your view model to composable you should follow what is described in the docs.

```
getViewModel() - fetch instance
```

By calling that method Koin will search for that view model and will provide with an instance.

Here is an example of injecting view model in my app.

```
fun ManualControlScreen(
  onDrawerClick: () -> Unit,
  viewModel: ManualControlViewModel = getViewModel<ManualControlViewModel>()
) {
   // Your composable UI
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@Composable
fun HomeScreen(viewModel: PokemonViewModel = koinViewModel()) {
}
```

*build.gradle(:app)*

```
def koin_version = '3.3.2'
implementation "io.insert-koin:koin-core:$koin_version"
implementation "io.insert-koin:koin-android:$koin_version"
implementation 'io.insert-koin:koin-androidx-compose:3.4.1'
```

[SOURCE](https://insert-koin.io/docs/reference/koin-android/compose)